# Search for custom field input of a custom post type in ajax live search

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, ajax, search

I have a custom post type (`gd_place` generated through GeoDirectory) with a custom field (`select_funding` as part of the table `wp_geodir_gd_place_detail`) where a user can choose one out of several options. I've built an ajax live search and now I want to include posts where the custom field input matches the search query. What would be the best approach for this?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I don't know your full arguments list that you pass into `get_posts` or `WP_Query`, but it seems like you need to use `meta_query`, check [Custom Field (post meta) Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the link, this definitely would have worked but I noticed that the plugin doesn't do it the wordpress way and instead creates a new column for a custom field in the table - not sure if there is any way to use it with meta_query in that case. But I was able to use your answer for something else, which is great!